# stateSave not preserving filters in shiny datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a data table in a shiny app.  Setting `stateSave = TRUE` preserves the sorting a column by ascending or descending, but if a filter parameter is set (cyl = 6:8 for example), that is not preserved.  Any idea on how to fix this?

Sample code is below:

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

ui<-fluidPage(
  column(12,
         DT::dataTableOutput("mtcars_table")
  )
)

server<-function(input,output,session)
{

  output$mtcars_table <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable({mtcars},
    options = list(pageLength = 50, 
                   stateSave = TRUE
    ),
    selection = "single", filter = "top", escape = FALSE)}, 
    server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Any updates on this since last year @User247365?

Answer (score 2):

It only works for server-side processing (set `server = TRUE`). 
Unfortunate, as you probably have a larger data set and it potentially causes performance issues.

The reason is quite simple. Not the filter is saved, but the filtered data set. Notice, upon the refresh you still see the data filtered correctly (with server- side processing) but the filter itself is not displayed anymore. You can see that is not stored if you click in the filter field and notice that the displayed range/selection does not match the attributes of the filtered data set.

For the server-side processing the data is kept on the server. If you filter the data and refresh the page the data will still be filtered. However, for non server-side processing the docu (`?renderDataTable`) tells you, that  *"the entire data frame is sent to the browser at once"*. Good bye filter :(.

Comment: Yes as you mentioned setting `server = TRUE` did cause performance issues and additionally did not maintain the filter.  So you are saying there is no way to maintain the filters, just the filtered data set without causing significant performance issues?

Comment: Ah then this could be of interest: github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/76: Especially: input$tbl_state. You could store the information in a file and reload it. Would that be a option or too dirty for a workaround?

Comment: Yeah I took an extensive look at that post before posting my own question and was unable to replicate yihui's solution.  I am getting an error `Error in datatable: unused argument (server = TRUE)`